# Administer AppFabric cache remotely

Tags: cache

I have written a website which administers my company's appfabric cache. I would like to deploy that website to a server other than the any within the cache cluster.

I have copied the powershell modules from my development machine to the web server, but when I fire up my website it says it's missing the Microsoft.ApplicationServer.StoreManagement assembly.

Now I could probably hack things by creating a zip file with all the assemblies it needs and install those manually into the GAC. But I would rather do things properly. So, is there a correct/supported way of installing the administration part of appfabric without installing the cache services?